# Installing Akelos - Fatal Error

Tags: php, frameworks, installation

I'm completely new to the Akelos framework, but I am familiar with PHP. When I came across the framework I knew it was exactly what I was looking for but for the life of me I cannot get it to install properly.

Here are the steps that I went through and the details of my environment:

1. I am on a Mac Intel, using MAMP as my main environment
2. I have copied the Akelos files into my project folder.
3. When I navigate to localhost:8888 (as setup by mamp) I first get this error message:

   > (Warning) Cannot modify header
   >   information - headers already sent by
   >   (output started at
   >   /Users/Salman/Work/_PERSONAL
   >   PROJECTS/Web
   >   Development/PHP_Development/SPM/public/index.php:50)

   But when I refreshed the page that warning disappears and I successfully obtain the Akelos Getting Started page
4. I setup the database configuration, and proceed
5. I successfully set the language settings
6. First I get the following error:

   > (User Error) Could not create or alter
   >   table akelos_migrations using the SQL
   >
   > CREATE TABLE akelos_migrations ( id
   >   INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name 
   >   VARCHAR(255), version
   >   INTEGER, updated_at
   >   DATETIME, created_at
   >   DATETIME,
   >                    PRIMARY KEY (id) )TYPE=InnoDB
7. When I refresh - everything "appears" to work fine and I am taken to to the "Welcome Aboard" page
8. When I try to run Script / Generate I get the following message:

   > Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] No
   >   such file or directory (trying to
   >   connect via
   >   unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in
   >   /Users/Salman/Work/_PERSONAL
   >   PROJECTS/Web
   >   Development/PHP_Development/SPM/vendor/adodb/drivers/adodb-mysql.inc.php
   >   on line 353
   >
   > Warning: mysql_connect(): No such file
   >   or directory in
   >   /Users/Salman/Work/_PERSONAL
   >   PROJECTS/Web
   >   Development/PHP_Development/SPM/vendor/adodb/drivers/adodb-mysql.inc.php
   >   on line 353
   >
   > Fatal error: Connection to the
   >   database failed.
   >   mysqlt://salman:******@localhost/socialPM_dev
   >   in /Users/Salman/Work/_PERSONAL
   >   PROJECTS/Web
   >   Development/PHP_Development/SPM/lib/AkActiveRecord/AkDbAdapter.php
   >   on line 66

This happens even if I try to manually create the akelos_migrations table using phpMyAdmin and SQL.

I would love to be able to use this framework - but I absolutely can't get past this!

Comment: I've removed the ruby on rails tag. I don't see the relation.

Comment: @zerk: Or at least why in the hell they used ADODB instead of PDO as a DB abstraction layer? Theres no reason for that nonsense.

Comment: @prodigitalson: because in some book for newbies (that they had read) only adodb was described

Comment: I apologize for the rails tag - Akelos didnt have a tag of its own and it is a self described PHP clone of the rails framework - which is why I included it.

Comment: Im not here to debate whether the developers of the frameworks are noobs or not - but if you feel like theres an alternative Rails based PHP framework - I would love to know about it!  Thanks!

Comment: @Salaman: Symfony 1.4 and CakePHP are similar to rails. Symfony2 also has code generation stuff, but isnt really all that similar to rails anymore. Im not Sure about CI and Kohana but i do think they have scaffolding generation like rails does.

Answer (score 0):

Well the mysql socket file isnt usually in `/var/mysql/mysql.sock` on OS X. If you use the Mysql install from Mysql then its in `/tmp/mysql.sock` by default... The macports version is in `/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock` by default. Im not sure where it is in MAMP because i dont use it, but my guess would be somewhere on the MAMP folder structure. You need to find out where it creates its socket and supply the path to it to your conifguration (i assume thats an option on the DB setup screen).

Comment: You are absolutely correct - thanks for pointing that out - MAMP stores the mysql.sock file in /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock (the tmp file forming when you start up MAMP).

Now I'm attempting to figure out how to change the default location (of /var/mysql/mysql.sock ) - somehow thats not appearing in the code anywhere - but I might try making a symbolic link of some sort

Comment: You might jsut try manually editing the configuration files... assuming Akelos lets you do that... A symlink should work though but id say thats less than optimal.